# Error in loading a csv with pandas which is space separated

Tags: python, csv, pandas, numpy

I have a csv file which I call `test.csv`. It is seprated by a . To check for it's correctness, I used `awk 'NR==**' test.csv | wc -w`  for different values of ** and made sure that it has 2595 columns as expected.

It has a header line. I loaded the csv as a numpy array using the following code:

```
 a = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", skip_header=1, delimiter=' ')
 a.shape
(3367, 2595)
```

And it loads the file correctly with 2595 columns.

When I loaded it with pandas using the following code, it loaded the file with the wrong number of columns.

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv", sep=' ')
test.shape
(3367, 2539)
```

Then I used `delim_whitespace=True` instead of `sep=' '` and it still gave the same result.

Finally, I used `index_col=False` and it threw an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Is this a bug in pandas or am I doing something wrong? I am using version `0.19.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the text, but my guess is that it's got something to do with the header row.

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv("text.csv", sep=" ", skiprows=1)
df.shape
```

Comment: test = pd.read_csv("../experiments/2500_ig_docfreq_5threshold/test.csv",
                  sep=' ', skiprows=1, header=None, index_col=None)


This worked. Thanks. I am pretty sure there are not spaces in the header row in the names. Should I share the header row or a few rows on the file by uploading it somewhere?

Comment: The problem is that Pandas is figuring out what the DataFrame should look like from the first row it parses, so if the header has no spaces, and the parser thinks that it's a data row, it will think the DataFrame should have a single column. If it really has has 2595 columns it's probably too big to share here. If you can upload the header and a few rows to somewhere else that would be helpful though.

Comment: Here's the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-NosSKmH7C3VUVmSld1SkdFbEk/view